# How do you add an object to a many-to-many relationship through a form on Django?

Tags: python, django

I have the following models:

```
class Exercise(models.Model):
    exercise = models.CharField(max_length=166)
    series = models.CharField(max_length=2)
    reps = models.CharField(max_length=2)
    station = models.ForeignKey(Station)


class Workout(models.Model):
    member = models.ForeignKey(Member, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    day = models.CharField(max_length=1)
    exercises = models.ManyToManyField(Exercise)
```

I want to be able to have a page where each `Workout` is displayed and the user can add `Exercises` when clicking a + button.

So, this would take the `Workout` ID from the URL, and when creating an `Exercise` would automatically associate it to that workout.

I was trying something along this line, but I don't think works:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
        np_form = NewWorkout(request.POST)
        ne_form = NovoExercise(request.POST)
    
        if ne_form.is_valid() and np_form.is_valid():
            nesave = ne_form.save()
            npsave = np_form.save(commit = False)
            npsave.exercises = nesave
            npsave.save()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that case you first save both objects, and then you add `nesave` to the `.exercises` of `npsave`. You should *not* save the `npsave`, since a `ManyToManyField` is not saved by that model, but by a "hidden" *through* model:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    np_form = NewWorkout(request.POST)
    ne_form = NovoExercise(request.POST)
    
    if ne_form.is_valid() and np_form.is_valid():
        nesave = ne_form.save()
        npsave = np_form.save()
        npsave.exercises.add(nesave)
```

If you however do *not* want to make a new workout but simply add a new exercise, you can do this with a view that contains the primary key of the `Workout`:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def my_view(request, pk):
    workout = get_object_or_404(Workout, pk=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        ne_form = NovoExercise(request.POST)
        
        if ne_form.is_valid():
            nesave = ne_form.save()
            workout.exercises.add(nesave)
```

Comment: I think I'm thinking this wrong, because I shouldn't have a `NewWorkout` form, because this should be "prefilled" through the url ID, and the new Exercise would automatically add to the workout.

Comment: @overclock: if you have the primary key of a workout, you can use the second code fragment. In that case you first fetch the `workout` from the database, and then add the new exercise to that workout.